# Is it cheating to wrap a large array in an object to avoid deep cloning in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, immutability

I am very confused.

Say I have a messages array that is structured like this:

```
this.state.messages = [
  { message_id: 0, body: "hello", author: "john" },
  { message_id: 1, body: "how", author: "lilly" },
  { message_id: 2, body: "are", author: "abe" },
  { message_id: 3, body: "you", author: "josh" }
];
```

and the user wants to edit the third message. React says to be immutable. That is, it is bad to do this:

```
this.state.messages[2].body = "test";
this.forceUpdate();
```

The problem with this is that React can't tell the messages state variable changed, because its reference is still the same. Firstly, does this even matter? I'm calling `forceUpdate` anyways, so it's going to re-render regardless. Shouldn't this only matter if you are using a `PureComponent` or a custom `shouldComponentUpdate` function?

Okay, well let's say it does matter (for some reason). Then it's advised to do a deep copy so that React knows the object changed. But how deep is deep enough?

For example, is it enough to do this?

```
let x = this.state.messages.slice(0);
x[2].body = "test";
this.setState({ messages: x });
```

This copies over the references to all the array elements, but it's not entirely deep! Because (before we do setState of course), `this.state.messages[0].body === x[0].body`. The string was not copied. It is still sharing internal state with the previous object. It is not a fully deep copy.

Okay, but if we don't need to do a full deep copy and the only thing that matters is that the parent node reference changes, then can we not just cheat and do this?

```
this.state.messages = { a: [
  { message_id: 0, body: "hello", author: "john" },
  { message_id: 1, body: "how", author: "lilly" },
  { message_id: 2, body: "are", author: "abe" },
  { message_id: 3, body: "you", author: "josh" }
]};

let x = { a: this.state.messages.a };
this.setState({ messages: x });
```

Now instead of copying over all the message references (of which there may be thousands), it is a single pointer change. But both messages are not deep copies. If the slice version is okay then should this not also be okay? Neither are deep copies it seems.

And if this latter method is okay, is there a more elegant way of writing it such that you don't need an arbitrary container object (`a` in this case)? A way to just change the pointer somehow to signal to React that the contents changed?

**Edit**: Okay, I don't think I explained myself well enough. Sorry, let me try again. Forget about performance for a second. What I'm wondering is: do you need to do deep clones or not for state updates? For example, what would be the *proper* way to update a body in the messages array in the example posted above? `.slice(0)` is not a deep copy, because it is still sharing internal structure (it is only copying references). Is this okay? Or do you need to do a deep copy to be proper? And if it IS okay, then should it not also be okay to just have a wrapper object and just only change THAT pointer instead?

**Further Edit**: I'm not sure if I'm just not explaining myself properly or if I am missing something very obvious. Does React need deep clones or not? I feel like this is an either-or sort of thing. I find it very doubtful that React requires 70% of a deep clone, but not 30%. Either it needs a full deep clone or it doesn't. If it doesn't, then shouldn't just changing a single wrapper pointer be enough? And if it isn't, then isn't `slice(0)` and `Object.assign` *also* not enough, because they are also shallow clones? In the case of these clones the internal objects still maintain the same structure (for example, the String references don't change).

Comment: Usually I'd use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) but if you find that slice will work faster you can do the following: `let x = this.state.messages.slice(0);x[2] = {...x[2],body:"test"};this.setState({ messages: x });`

Comment: This is not a deep clone though. The rest of the internal structure is the same. I've explained this to every answer so far, and in the original post.

Comment: The rest should be the same, you don't want to re render thousands of messages because you changed one message do you? All the code you posted are mutating so if your messages are pure components they would not re render. If you want to mutate for performance and then force update to let react shadow dom compare thousands of messages then you're not optimizing your code correctly.

Comment: @HMR: Okay, if that is the case then (that you DON'T want to deep clone), is a wrapper object not the ideal choice then? Since it only requires a pointer change and not moving all the keys from one object to another?

Comment: Your "wrapper" object example doesn't change any of the messages, if you would then you'd mutate it. I can see only one reason to mutate and force update and that is that you only show a couple of messages so mutating state would be quick and force update the couple of messages shown.

Comment: Please note that slice would not copy the elements in the array, it would only create a new array with the same elements. When you do copy a reference type (slice with array or {...o} with object) it is always a shallow copy so ding `copy.prop=new` would not mutate the original but `copy.prop.prop` or `copy[index].prop` will mutate the original.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be using force updates.
You shouldn't mutate the state object - it should be immutable for a reason (easier to debug, better performance, etc)

https://redux.js.org/faq/immutable-data#what-are-the-benefits-of-immutability

https://medium.com/@kkranthi438/dont-mutate-state-in-react-6b25d5e06f42

https://daveceddia.com/why-not-modify-react-state-directly/

Do not worry about performance unless there is a real performance issue - premature optimizations like this could actually harm performance, and slow your development (it makes your app harder to debug).

"Thousands of objects" is nothing to modern day computers / mobile devices. There are many other things you could try before breaking the immutability convention - you could try to split your state in smaller chunks, use selectors, better organize your components so not everything has to be re-rendered when only a small chunk of your state changed.

It's usually better to use flat / simple objects for your `state` - so it's much easier to create new copies of them. (when you do `Object.assign` or `{ ...foo }` you are only getting shallow copies.) If you can't do away with deep nested objects you could try to add a 3rd party library like immutability-helper, or `lodash.cloneDeep`

---

In short, only update your state with `setState` - try to avoid `forceUpdate` and things like `this.state.foo = bar`. Even if some deeply nested objects are still referencing their old state, as long as you are following the rules you should be ok in most cases.

However do try to keep your state objects shallow whenever possible.

---

In your example, you mentioned `this.state.messages[0].body === x[0].body` the string is **indeed** copied. Strings are always copied in JS. your expression is comparing two string values - not their references.

```
// Given:
let obj = { foo: { bar: 'baz' } };

let fooObj = obj.foo; // fooObj is a reference to obj.foo;
let str = obj.foo.bar; // str is a COPY of the string 'baz';

str === fooOjb.bar // true, you are comparing their values, not references.

obj.foo.bar = 'baz2';

fooObj === obj.foo; // true, because you are comparing their references.

str === obj.foo.bar // false - str value does not change when obj.foo.bar changes.
```

---

Is immutability **absolutely required** in `react`?

Short answer: NO. You can do whatever you want. React is not going to throw errors at you when parts of your new state is still referencing to the old state.

However, never mutate your state directly. Always do it via `setState`. Don't worry too much about if your state object is 100% deep cloned or not. As long as you can make sure no parts of your app modifies your state, `React` can handle the rest.

Comment: Let's say a trillion objects then. I'm just curious about the actual answer from a technical curiosity rather than pragmatic standpoint.

Comment: It's still nothing comparing to the amount of renders you will be doing - if all of your objects are used. rendering the DOM tree and compare them to decide which parts of update is much more expensive than copying some objects - and with `forceUpdate` you might be forcing react to do it more than it has to.

Comment: Maybe I'm not explaining myself properly. Forget about performance for a second. To write "proper" React, do you need to do a deep clone for all state changes or not? If you have the same structure as my messages array in the OP, what is the proper way to do setState? Since `.slice(0)` is not a deep clone, does that not violate React's immutability guidelines?

Comment: If you have trillions of objects in your state you probably should really be looking into optimizing your components so each of them is only using a small chunk of the state (so each change only affects a small amount of components).

Comment: You don't **need** to do a deep clone - however it is highly recommended to do so. I edited my answer about deeply nested objects. You should be fine as long as your code is not mutating the state directly - like you said some objects are not deep clones - but it probably won't produce bugs if you only rely on `setState` to change them.

Comment: Immutability is not absolutely required in `React` (without redux). Just don't change state directly without `setState` you should be fine in 99% of the cases. However sticking to shallower objects & deep clones **could** make your life easier in the long run.

Comment: This all seems so vague/wishywashy. It's recommended, but not needed? It "probably" won't produce bugs? It "could" make my life easier? I'm getting a vibe that this doesn't actually matter from React's perspective and it's just tradition/superstition?

Comment: Yes, `react` is not forcing your state to be absolutely immutable - but having immutable objects has a lot of benefits so you should try to take advantage of it. You can drive a car with one hand - but having both hands on the wheel is always a better choice.

Comment: Based on what you're saying it seems you are advocating for cloning all the string values as well. It's either a deep clone or not. It seems strange to advocate for 80% of a deep clone but not 40%. The actual answer must be that it either matters or it doesn't.

Comment: String values (and other primitives) are always cloned in JavaScript. You don't need to do anything special. The rule of thumb is always use `setState` - and again I would avoid having deeply nested state objects as much as possible.

Comment: This is hardly deeply nested. It's a single layer of nesting, which is required in most apps. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by string values are always cloned in JavaScript. In all the examples posted on this question these values are not cloned. For example, doing `messages.slice(0)` does not clone the string values. The references to the strings are identical between the clone and the original.

Comment: if you have an object `obj = { foo: 'bar' }` and you do `baz = obj.foo` then string `bar` is cloned into `baz`. When you do `obj.foo = 'barbar'` the value in `baz` is still going to be `"bar"`. In your example the problem is not the string, but the object itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199637/discussion-between-yurui-zhang-and-ryan-peschel).

Answer (score 0):

There is a really good example of storing Todo list as a map of todo items and list of its' ids:

```
const state = {
  todos: {
    0: "Buy a milk",
    1: "Buy a bread",
  },
  todosList: [0, 1]
}
```

Maybe you should split your state and store `messages` as map with `ID` as a key. It gives you a `O(1)` time for adding, changing and deleting messages.

And if you would store a messages map as a separate state, you'll be able to change any message like this:

```
this.setState({
  [messageId]: newValue
})
```

Comment: Another way is to use Immutable Data Structures, they have an internal optimization s to prevent copying a bunch of data.

Comment: I did not explain myself well enough. I'm going to edit the OP.

Comment: What does `OP` mean?

Comment: Original post  .

Comment: As for me it seems OK. I've made a sandbox example https://codesandbox.io/s/little-field-o34u7. It shows that the reference on `messages` state prop is changes when you make `setState` after `slice` and modify.

Answer (score 0):

Stop mutating your data!

One of React's primary features is doing change detection on data held in the  'state' object. The key to this change detection is to make sure you are always using previous state, modifying whatever data you need and React will handle the change detection, then update the UI accordingly and as efficiently as possible.

```
this.setState((prevState)=> {
  return {
    ...prevState,
    messages: prevState.messages.map((obj,i)=> i === 2 ? { ...obj, body:"test" } : obj)
  }
})
```

Comment: This is not a deep clone or immutable change though. The internal structure is still the same except for that one change. How does this differ from React's perspective from just changing the wrapper pointer and modifying the internal value?

Comment: @RyanPeschel Thats absolutely wrong, what data is being mutated? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: Try doing something like `console.log(originalState.messages[0].body === clonedState.messages[0].body)` They are the same reference, so it's not a deep clone.

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't know JavaScript copied strings like primitive types and not reference types.